# Call to nextLine() needed thrice for reading a string after it has read int and double in java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, user-input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Read input */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i    = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();              // gets rid of the pesky newline
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();
        
        /* Print output */
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

The above code works perfectly fine in hackerrank compiler. While if i run it on IntelliJ, one extra call to scan.nextLine() is required in order to read the actual string.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Read input */
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i    = scan.nextInt();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();              // gets rid of the pesky newline
        scan.nextLine();              // gets rid of the pesky newline
        String s = scan.nextLine();
        scan.close();

        /* Print output */
        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
}
```

Can someone help me with why this could happen? I am assuming the call to nextDouble() would ignore the \n left in the buffer by nextInt() and pickup the next double token and leave a new \n in the buffer. So a single call to nextLine() should be enough to clear that \n from buffer, but why 2 calls are needed when I run this on IntelliJ.

Is this a JAVA version issue or is there something really basic which I am missing?

Comment: I believe that it’s an IntelliJ IDEA bug and that it has been asked about before.

Comment: What is your IDEA version?

Comment: It's IntelliJ IDEA 2022.1.1 (Runtime version: 11.0.14.1+1-b2043.45 x86_64)

Comment: Shall i ignore the issue then? And using nextLine() just once is enough?

Answer (score 1):

You probably see the effect of this official IDEA issue: [Console readLine skips input in 2022.1.1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293951)

You could update to 2022.1.2 where this is fixed.